# How to trigger drop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, triggers

```
$(item).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("triggered");
    }
});
```

I try to call drop by

```
$(item).trigger("drop", [{},{draggable : $(target_item)}]);
```

But it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I understand that you want to simulate a drag and drop, did you find any solution?

Comment: yes correct, no if I remember correct I didn't.

Comment: @adardesign http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284621/278405?programmatically-drag-and-drop-element-onto-another-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want to do is:

```
$(item).bind('dropthis', function(e){
        console.log('triggered');
}).droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).trigger('dropthis',[event, ui]);
        }
});
```

And call the drop event by:

```
$(item).trigger("dropthis", [{},{draggable : $(target_item)}]);
```

Comment: no, in the other way, I want to trigger "as it would be" the user who dropped a item, not a user by himself.

Comment: now looking back on this old question. It looks correct solution :P

Answer (score 0):

try out [jQuery.simulate plugin](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/jquery-simulate/blob/master/jquery.simulate.js)

Something like this should work.

```
var dropZone = $("#dropZone").offset() //get dropZone's offset object
$("#dragableEle").simulate("drag", {
     dx: dropZone.left, // move to this x
     dy: dropZone.top, // move to this y
     speed:5000 // set speed
});
```

Comment: Oops, I now tested and looks like its not triggering a drop, wonder why, ill try to debug, let me know if you get somewhere.